# unable to connect to internet via router

Tags: debian, internet, router, devuan

I'm on Dell Latitude 3420, Devuan Daedalus GNU/Linux (based on Debian Bookworm, without systemd),

I connect to internet via mobile hotspot (using Android Phone's mobile data) at home and through a router installed by a service provider at office.

Recently, I have not been able to connect to internet at office, both ethernet and WiFi.
WiFi and LAN icons show that they are connected to the router, but no internet access.

Can someone please help me out?

What further information would be needed from my end?
I'm  a Linux user since 2010. Quite used to CLI commands.
Windows OS on other office PCs connect well to the router.

Please edit tags if necessary.

Regards,

**EDIT**

`*resolvconf.conf*`

```
# Configuration for resolvconf(8)
# See resolvconf.conf(5) for details

resolv_conf=/etc/resolv.conf
# If you run a local name server, you should uncomment the below line and
# configure your subscribers configuration files below.
#name_servers=127.0.0.1


# Mirror the Debian package defaults for the below resolvers
# so that resolvconf integrates seemlessly.
dnsmasq_resolv=/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
pdnsd_conf=/etc/pdnsd.conf
unbound_conf=/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/resolvconf_resolvers.conf
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know if you are using a static or DHCP network config, to see the IP address netamask and default route both from your Dell and your phone (temporarily switch phone's network config to "static" and it will show you the current settings)

Comment: @GAD3R The laptop was getting connected earlier. This is just a recent issue.

Comment: What is the IP address of the laptop?

Comment: @symcbean can you give me the exact commands?

Comment: @eyoung100 how to check that?

Comment: Try `ifconfig` in a terminal.  Paste the results in as an edit to your post.  Do not take a screenshot, as those are sometimes hard to read.

Comment: @eyoung100 `bash: ifconfig: command not found`. But `net-tools` is installed. How can this happen?

Comment: Try `ip addr`  We will figure out the other problem once we fix the connection

Comment: Install the openresolv package

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the openresolv package, edit the resolvconf.conf with the proper dns servers, and then run `resolvconf -u`

Comment: Thank you. please see the edits.

Comment: It looks like you haven't edited it yet, you need to uncomment the name servers part and put a dns resolver in there. In the nameservers part include the opendns nameservers for example. They are very reliable resolvers. `208.67.222.222` and `208.67.220.220`